# Obtaining probability generating function by solving a functional equation

Tags: functional-equations

For investigating a queueing model in my research, I need to obtain the probability generating function (PGF), $G(z)$, by solving the following functional equation
$$\lambda(z(1-p)+p)G((1-p)z)-(\mu+\lambda p)(1-p)G(z)=(\lambda p-(\mu+\lambda p)(1-p))\pi_0$$
where $\lambda, \mu, p, \pi_0$ are parameters, and $0<p<1$.

Since $G(z)$ is a PGF, it is known that $G(0)=\pi_0$ and $G(1)=1$. Also, by substituting $z=1$, I get
$$G(1-p)=\frac{(\lambda p-(\mu+\lambda p)(1-p))\pi_0+(\mu+\lambda p)(1-p)}{\lambda}$$
In addition, by substituting $z=1/(1-p)$, $z=1-p$ and $z=(1-p)^2$, I have
$$G(\frac{1}{1-p})=\frac{\lambda(1+p)-(\lambda p-(\mu+\lambda p)(1-p))\pi_0}{(\mu+\lambda p)(1-p)})$$
$$G((1-p)^2)=\frac{(\lambda p-(\mu+\lambda p)(1-p))\pi_0+(\mu+\lambda p)(1-p)G(1-p)}{\lambda}$$
$$G((1-p)^3)=\frac{(\lambda p-(\mu+\lambda p)(1-p))\pi_0+(\mu+\lambda p)(1-p)G(1-p)^2}{\lambda}$$
Since $G(z)$ is a PGF it cannot be a polynomial function. So, I assumed that the function is of form
$$G(z)=\frac{az^2+bz+c}{dz^2+ez+f}$$
and tried to calculate the coefficients $a, b, c, d, e, f$ by solving the set of six equations using the six expressions above, i.e.,
$$\frac{c}{f}=\pi_0$$
$$\frac{a+b+c}{d+e+f}=1$$
$$\frac{a(1-p)^2+b(1-p)+c}{d(1-p)^2+e(1-p)+f}=G(1-p)$$
$$\frac{a(1/(1-p))^2+b(1/(1-p))+c}{d(1/(1-p))^2+e(1/(1-p))+f}=G(1/(1-p))$$
$$\frac{a(1-p)^4+b(1-p)^2+c}{d(1-p)^4+e(1-p)^2+f}=G((1-p)^2)$$
$$\frac{a(1-p)^6+b(1-p)^3+c}{d(1-p)^6+e(1-p)^3+f}=G((1-p)^3)$$

However, there is no possible solution for this set. I will appreciate if some one could help me.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Denote $q=1-p.$ If you write $G(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$ then $$a_n=G(0)\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{p-(\mu+\lambda p)q^{-k}}.$$ Certainly $G$ is not elementary, in particular is not the quotient of two polynomials. Expanding a rational fraction in a power series is done by writing it in sum of  $(1-rz) ^{-k}$, essentially giving $a_n=\sum_{r\in R}P_r(n)r^n$ when $n$ is big enough -Here $R$ is a finite set of complex numbers and $P_r$ is a polynomial. So, no way...